# problemas al asignar icono y ruta a cada item de un map

Tags: api, lista, flutter, listview, map

estoy desarronllando un vista en flutter donde debo listar un menu de opciones, pero resulta que cada item debe tener un  icono, y una ruta el cual lo va a dirgir hacia otra pantalla, como puedo hacer eso?, esto es lo que recibo de mi api,puedo listarlo guardando mi varialble en un list.genarate,usando como widget un listtle, pero el inconveniente es que cada item, se genera con el mismo icono y la misma ruta .

API
opcion: {
"informacion": 1,
"libreta": 0,
"informes": 0,
"hoja": 0,
"asistencia": 0,
"otras": 1
},

Comment: clave es el nombre de cada item y el valor es si esta activo o inactivo esa opcion

Comment: Intenta agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, para poder trabajar sobre ese código

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto sea de ayuda

primero recorre tu data

```
  final List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
  setState(() {
    menuItems = data.map((item) => MenuItem(
      title: item['title'],
      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.fromString(item['icon']),
      route: item['route'],
    )).toList();
  });
```

despues lo muestras en listview widget con su respectivo navigator

```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: menuItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final menuItem = menuItems[index];
       return ListTile(
        leading: Icon(menuItem.icon),
        title: Text(menuItem.title),
         onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, menuItem.route);
         },
       );
      },
     );
    }
```

recuerda llamar el widget en tu body principal

PD: construye tu json api con tres opciones titulo, icono y nombre de la ruta para que puedas navegar